# background image not display in css code

Tags: css

I have an image which is not displayed as expected in the browser.
How do I solve this error?
I've got the following code, but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

```css
html {
   background-image: url(demo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -0-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: the selector tag should be `body`. url is incorrect. provide an absolute path in snippets.

Comment: Very easy to fix: provide correct path. Btw, *`-0-background-size`*: zero? you have no idea what those `-X-` mean, do you..

Answer (score 1):

> At first you should check your `Image Path` in `url(demo.jpg)`

If your image path is correct, It should work.

And change

```
-0-background-size
```

To

```
-o-background-size
```

```css
html {
    background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/3d/0c/0b/3d0c0ba69a64eb7105688e9ca5cddab5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Funny, you copy the fix of my answer, correct some secondary minor mistakes and get upvoted. Crazy world.

Comment: You just skipped his mistake about `0` and did not describe about it in your answer! And also didn't describe about main point `image Path` @JanNahody

Answer (score 0):

Well your mistake is that `background-image` has multiple values. `background-image` can contain ONLY the url! `background` can contain multiple values.
So you use `background` with multiple values or specify every background property.

So this should be correct:

```css
html {
    background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/70/69/52/706952eab7649280a7bd679aed184b98.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```